# Why does MVN return -1 on successful build?

Tags: java, maven-2

I'm running Maven 2.2.1 and it's returning an exit code of -1 even though it states that the build is successful. Anyone know what causes this exit code to occur as it's breaking our build process?

As a further tidbit of information MVN is being called from our MS TFS build server which is where this problem occurs. If I can MVN from the command line the exit code is 0.

Here's the Reactor Summary:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Reactor Summary:
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Aquarius Web App ...................................... SUCCESS [6.655s]
  [INFO] Aquarius Flex Library ................................. SUCCESS [1:26.329s]
  [INFO] Aquarius Flex Application ............................. SUCCESS [31.412s]
  [INFO] Aquarius Web Archive .................................. SUCCESS [5:22.484s]
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Total time: 8 minutes 34 seconds
  [INFO] Finished at: Mon Oct 25 10:19:50 BST 2010
  [INFO] Final Memory: 62M/225M
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you having failed tests?What phase did you call mvn test or mvn package ?

Comment: Perhaps you could post the last 10 or so lines of output? Possibly using the -X flag?

Comment: As far as I can see I have no failures but I do have a number of warnings.

Comment: @khmarbaise it was mvn package.

Comment: How do you check the exit code (windows / linux?) ? Have you called mvn, cause mvn on windows is a batch file which has to be called to get a correct return code (As far as i can remember not sure?)

Comment: The exit code is being checked by TFS build server. I've verified that the batch file is being called by the build server. Unfortunately I don't have control over how the TFS build server calls maven or how it handles the return code. I'm going to look at creating a wrapper batch file that handles this -1 exit code on a way that TFS doesn't abend.

Comment: Does this happens with all of your maven builds or just one job in particular? Can you post the evidence of the -1 return code that you see? (I'm guessing that will probably be a TFS screenshot)

Comment: Does TFS add any plugins that could be failing after the engine reports a successful build? I've seen similar behavior out of Hudson when its injected behavior fails.

Comment: You are going to need to run Maven with the -e and the -X flag and then post the entire output somewhere (maybe as a Gist).   If you can't do that then any answer here is going to be  a guess.